# Print dereferenced structs from slice of pointers to structs

Tags: go

In Golang, is there an easy way to print for debugging the dereferenced pointers given a slice of pointers to structs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use unsafe and an external package.. you can `range` over it yourself:

```
for _, p := range people {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
}
```

Output:

```
&{name:Simon age:25}
&{name:Bob age:31}
```

Working sample: http://play.golang.org/p/aVw0rhQNuk

Comment: There is more choice with the Printf string: try out `"%v\n"`, `"%+v\n"` and `"%#v\n"` to give different amounts of information.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's a late answer, but I've just come across the same problem and wanna save my choice here for anyone needed.

I added a `String()` function to my item type. For example:

```
type SliceItem struct {
    ID   int32
    Name string
}

func (i *SliceItem) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("id = %d, name = %s\n", i.ID, i.Name)
}
```

As a result, whenever I wanna print this item, I got friendly "id = xx, name = xxx" string, instead of unreadable pointer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print individual elements, try it with the index and asterix for dereferencing:

```golang
fmt.Println(*pointer_strcut_slice[0])
fmt.Println(*pointer_strcut_slice[1])
```